# FFmpeg Converted files not working on firefox

Tags: firefox, video, ffmpeg, html5

When i convert a file with ffmpeg and play the video in firefox i get this error :

```
"VIDEOJS:" "ERROR:" "(CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE)" "The video playback was aborted due to a     corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support." Object { code: 3, message: "The video playback was aborted due to a corruption problem or because the video used features your browser did not support." }
```

In other browsers it's working perfect.
This is my ffmpeg convert command:

```
ffmpeg -i {input} -b 5500k -minrate 5500k -maxrate 5500k -bufsize 5500k -ab 384k -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -ar 96000 -s 1280x720 -y {output}
```

Can someone tell me why the videos won't play in firefox?

Comment: Please do not cross-post [the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998648/ffmpeg-converted-files-not-working-on-firefox) in multiple [se] sites.

Comment: x264 playing support on firefox is platform dependant.

Answer (score 0):

H.264 support on Firefox depends on OS. According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats), this is the platform support:

```
Platform        Gecko (Firefox) version
Windows 7+      21.0
Windows Vista   22.0
Android         20.0
Firefox OS      15.0
Linux           26.0 (relies on GStreamer codecs being installed)
OS X 10.7       Not yet
```

> [...] Since H.264 is currently not a royalty free format, it is unfit for the open web platform, according to Mozilla, Google and Opera. However, since royalty free formats are not supported by Internet Explorer and Safari, Mozilla has decided to support the format anyway [...]
>
> Firefox/Firefox for Android/Firefox OS **supports the format in some cases**, but **only when a third-party decoder is available**, and the device hardware can handle the profile used to encode the MP4.